# f.select doesn't change model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have model called Polynom and model parametres are degree and type, i have form

```ruby
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :degree %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :degree %>
</div>

<div>
  <%= f.label :type %><br />
  <%= f.select :type, options_for_select(
                        [ "Laguerre Polynomials", "Legendre Polynomials" ]
                      )
  %>
</div>
```

When i submit this form - degree changes, but type doesn't change. What i do wrong? degree is integer, and type is string values. Please help cause i dont know what to do

Comment: Can you please add you controller method where you are saving the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type is a reserved word - try renaming the attribute polytype or something ...